# Compass is adding path to my data uri

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am using the [Compass inline-image helper](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/inline-data/) in my project but while it does seem to be creating a data uri it also is adding a path to the start of the result.

I have no errors from `compass watch` either.

Here is the SCSS:

```
.myelement {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 42px;
    text-indent: -10000px;
    width: 29px;
    background-image: inline-image('myimage.gif');
}
```

And here is the compiled CSS:

```
.myelement {
    background-image: url("http://myproject/foo/bar/css/data:image/gif;base64,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");
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 42px;
    text-indent: -10000px;
    width: 29px;
}
```

As you can see, the data uri is being generated but `http://myproject/foo/bar/css/` is getting added which makes the url invalid.

My config.rb:

```
require "zurb-foundation"
# Require any additional compass plugins here.


# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed
output_style = :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
 line_comments = false


# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
# preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you show your config.rb of compass? It looks like compass try to add absolute path for your image. Try to add this line into config.rb `relative_assets = true`

Comment: I have added my config.rb